# How to zoom a single image in a photo scroller (UIScrollView)

Tags: ios5, uiscrollviewdelegate, pinchzoom

I have a UIScrollView which has about 10+ images laid out horizontally using the following code adapted from apple sample code:

```
- (void)layoutScrollViewImages
{
    UIImageView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [scrollView subviews];
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);

            view.frame = frame;
        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);

        }
    }
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth),[scrollView bounds].size.height)];
}
```

The user can page through the images one at a time, in a horizontal manner, but I want each individual image zoomable. I have tried returning my scrollView in viewForZoomingInScrollView but that seems to zoom the entire scrollview, not the individual image. Additionally, I have tried setting the UIImageView as a property and returning that, but still have not had any success. Additionally, I have tried adding a pinch gesture recognizer in storyboard, but that did not work AT ALL. So looking for some guidance on essentially how to return the individual UIImageView within an array of scrollView.subviews.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something similar to Apples Photo Library effect, where you can swipe from image to image but zoom / scroll per individual image.

You are going to have to put each subview inside it's own zooming scrollview. Then each one can scroll independently of the others.

Take a look at Apple's 'photoscroller' sample code (just search for photoscroller in the docs). There is also a WWDC video to accompany the code (WWDC 2010, "Designing Apps with Scroll Views")